# How could the C++ Builder XE debugger be affecting my code?

Tags: c++builder-xe

Using C++ builder XE

I'm using a TStatusBar on a form with 2 panels. The first panel is just text. The second is set to OwnerDraw and should indicate a red or green panel showing if a comport is connected or not. This is updated from a TTimer on a form with an interval of 500ms.
What seems to happen is that when I run the program from within the IDE (with the debugger), it works OK, but when I run it from the .exe file in the destination folder, of from within the IDE without the debugger, it doesn't update the status bar.

This is really annoying, because as soon as I run it under the debugger to debug it, it doesn't go wrong !
It seems that the OnDrawPanel event handler is not getting called when I'm not using the debugger.
Anyone got any ideas why, or a way round this ?

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are likely just not using the owner-drawn panel correctly in general.

Comment: I've fixed it. I had a comment that had got uncommented and was calling an old (and buggy) method. Don't have time to retrospectively find out what was happening, but it was some interaction between the TTimer and the TStatusBar OnDraw event.